# Как узнать, из какого элемента была вызвана функция?

Tags: javascript, html, функции

В программе нужно знать, из какого именно тега div была вызвана функция

```
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r1"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r2"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r3"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r4"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r5"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r6"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r7"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r8"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r9"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat()" id = "r10"></div>
```

---

я переделал код

```
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat1()" id = "r1"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat2()" id = "r2"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat3()" id = "r3"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat4()" id = "r4"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat5()" id = "r5"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat6()" id = "r6"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat7()" id = "r7"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat8()" id = "r8"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat9()" id = "r9"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat10()" id = "r10"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat11()" id = "r11"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat12()" id = "r12"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat13()" id = "r13"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat14()" id = "r14"></div>
        <div class="nob" onclick = "eat15()" id = "r15"></div>
```

Comment: В данной реализации - никак.

Comment: навесьте еще один обработчик события click и передавайте ему ID элемента (как this.id).

Comment: @Инквизитор, зачем еще один?

Comment: Обработчики надо вешать через `addEventListener` и определять элемент через `this` или `event.target`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, не обязательно

Comment: @Grundy Если `HTML` и позволяет так делать `onclick="eat(event)"`, хорошим советом, я бы это не назвал. Да и кода куда бы меньше было без копирования `onclick` в каждом `div`.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, спорный вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy А что тут спорить. Это `document.querySelectorAll('div.nob').forEach((e)=>e.addEventListener('click', eat))` короче 4-ех "HTML-навешиваний".

Comment: Но так же это может быть дополнительной загрузкой файла, а так же дополнительной работой по выборке элементов

Comment: @Grundy, вдруг человек колупает что-то, что нельзя изменить, например, приходящий с сервера контент. Зато можно добавить ивентЛистенер и радоваться.
Если код свой, то да, проще добавить в онклик еще одну функцию, или имеющуюся заставить что-то делать с ID.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, передать функции `id` как аргумент.

```
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat('r1')" id = "r1"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat('r2')" id = "r2"></div>
<div class="nob" onclick = "eat('r3')" id = "r3"></div>
```